# PHPUnit Testing - Controllers or Models

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I am using the Laravel framework and was reading through Laravel Testing Decoded by Jeffrey Way.  It goes into depth on how to test and why to test, and talks about testing anything and everything.

My question is this: ***If I am performing most of my tests on my model, do I need to test my controllers in depth as well?***

For instance, my model tests validation, it tests saving, hashing passwords, miscellaneous functions... all which can be called by the controller.  My controller just receives the request, calls the model method(s), and then serves up the view.

The section on controller testing shows that you can test the controller for validation, redirects, model saving, etc.  It seems like a lot of this is repetitious, and there should be no need to test validation and saving if I have tests that do that already on the model level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the question to ask is:

- Q. Suppose all your other components work perfectly well and then some day you'll want to change your controller for whatever reason, maybe adding new components or whatever. Now after this change, suddenly the old functionality of this controller is broken. Will it be easy for you to remember the way you designed it and fix it? Or will you rather save your some headache by running few test that tell you exactly where it is broken?

If you trust the advice of Uncle Bob that he gives in his fantastic book "Clean Code", you are "not allowed" to write a single line of a code before writing a test that fails.

Here are some of his videos, highly recommended:

[Robert C Martin(Uncle Bob) -Clean Architecture and Design... - Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asLUTiJJqdE)

[Ruby Midwest 2011 - Keynote: Architecture the Lost Years... - Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884)

Works great in theory but I have myself [problems with tests in practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882474/designing-robust-and-testable-architecture-for-importing-large-text-data-from-3r)